# Getting carousel list of dialogflow's V2 in Skype

Tags: json, carousel, dialogflow-es

I have been trying to get the carousel list on Skype. I have used the JSON specified in 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#CarouselSelect
but the Skype isn't rendering it or the facebook messenger. If I'm sending a list of cards using
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Card
then the Skype is rendering a vertical listview and Messenger is rendering a carousel list. And the carousel select is working fine in V1 of Dialogflow using the message object 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects#custom_payload_message_object_2 using which I'm able to send a custom payload to get the individual platforms, and also sending it in a payload in V2 didn't help.
Is there's a way to achieve the carousel list in Skype using DialogFlow V2? If it's possible to make this happen using payload, please reply with the JSON.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: skype is not supporting carousel list like facebook

Comment: Skype does support the carousel list, do see the images and the documentation for it. We have to specify it to display as carousel list https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I cracked it!

The default list view in messenger in a carousel and the default list view of Skype is normal vertical list view. For most of the official documents that I have seen for Skype bot development, Skype encourages its developers to use defined libraries using which the JSON is created and sent to the bot. Messenger, on the other hand, has many resources on the JSON format.

**in DialogFlow V1:**
In the message object, we get to add the details like the type of payload and the platform we are expected to send it to. More can be read at
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects

So, the carousel in Skype is achieved by adding the Skype bot's attribute `attachmentType`
This specifies if the item is of carousel else is of normal list view.
The JSON format is specified at
https://miningbusinessdata.com/dialogflow-api-ai-skype-integration/

This is how a custom payload data is sent to Skype bot. Here, we can send a list of items in `attachments` array with the type and Skype shall interpret it.

**in DialogFlow V2-Beta:**
There are 2 ways I have identified using which we can send data to Skype/Messenger using V2-Beta.

1. Using the predefined templates given by dialogflow
   https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Message
   This provides the `card, image, carousel` views. When a list of `card` objects is sent to Skype, it displays it as a vertical list and when sent to Messenger, it displays it as Carousel list. But, the Skype and Messenger didn't seem to support the `carousel` template
   So the other option we are left with is sending data in the custom payload.
2. For sending it in a custom payload, there are 2 payloads in V2. 
   Inside `Message` object of the `webHookResponse`
   https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Message

The other payload is in the `webHookResponse` we shall send.
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookResponse

Both of these are JSON objects and sending it in the `Message` object actually works and with a proper JSON format. The JSON format of the Skype when being sent as a custom payload has very fewer resources available.

```
"platform":"SKYPE",
"payload":
       {
        "skype":
            {
              "attachmentLayout":"carousel",                                                                    
              "attachments":[
                      {        
                        "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                        "content":{
                                    "title":
                                    "subtitle":
                                    "images":[{"url":}],
                                    "buttons":[{
                                        "type":"postBack",
                                        "title": 
                                        "value": 
                                    }]
                          }
                 ]
             }
        }
```

Using this the list of cards are sent to Skype and the list is displayed as Carousel list. On later searching I found out
https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/microsoft-bot-framework-messages-howto-image-html-card-button-etc/
It has the list of different JSONs that we can send to Skype

Happy Coding!